# How can I get Mail to open .ics invites with my Google Calendar?

Tags: calendar, ical, google

Right now double-clicking the invite adds it to an iCloud calendar that I don't use, so I have to manually change calendars when I accept an invite.

Answer (score 1):

I am researching this problem with how iPhones handle calendar invites defaulting to iCal instead of using my Google Calendar and found [this easy fix](http://ternarylabs.com/2015/01/30/fix-missing-ical-to-gmail-invites/).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Please avoid link-only answers.  Links may change over time and the answer to this question may be lost.  Please see [answer] on how to provide a good answer.  - From Review -